# If Label text is blank, fill in text

Tags: ios, uitableview, rss, uilabel

I'm pulling in information from an RSS feed, and **sometimes the `title` and/or `description` are blank**, so it will show blank in the `UITableViewCell`.

So **if** the `title` and/or `description` is **blank**, I'd like to **fill it in as `Title` and/or `Description`**.

*What I have:*

```
    cell.labelHeadline.text = title;
    cell.labelDescription.text = description;
```

*What I tried:*

```
   if ([cell.labelHeadline.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        cell.labelHeadline.text = @"Title";
    } else {
        cell.labelHeadline.text = title;
    }

    if ([cell.labelDescription.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        cell.labelDescription.text = @"Description";
    } else {
        cell.labelDescription.text = description;
    }
```

What I tried doesn't work... Have any ideas?

Will post any extra code as needed, thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your condition you are checking the value of labels placed in the cell not the value getting from server.
Instead of that you need to check the values retrieved from server, I think you want to change your conditions like:

```
    if ([title isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        cell.labelHeadline.text = @"Title";
    }
    else
    {
        cell.labelHeadline.text = title;
    }

    if ([description isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        cell.labelDescription.text = @"Description";
    }
    else
    {
        cell.labelDescription.text = description;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, exactly what I needed!  Was checking the value of the labels instead of value from server.  Thanks!